# Regex exclusive capture between strings (VB.NET)

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm sure an answer for exists several times over but I can't seem to find an example of capture between two strings, excluding the two strings.

Line of text:

```
CH1: Vcc: 3220 mV TXBias 14144 RX pwr: 0 TX pwr: 7184\n
```

output I desire:

```
3220 mV
```

What I've tried:

```
 Regex.Match("CH1: Vcc: 3220 mV TXBias 14144 RX pwr: 0 TX pwr: 7184\n", "Vcc: (.*?) ").ToString
```

yields:

```
 Vcc: 3220
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, provide more samples of input strings and desired output. May be this one `Regex.Match("CH1: Vcc: 3220 mV TXBias 14144 RX pwr: 0 TX pwr: 7184\n", "\d+ mV").ToString` will work for you.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, this is not what I want--I gave a very clear example. I wish to capture *after* the string "Vcc: " and not include that. I do not wish to match using a numeric string capture. Thank you.

Comment: After `Vcc:` till where?

Comment: For example, the following one captures text between `Vcc: ` and `TXBias`: `Regex.Match("CH1: Vcc: 3220 mV TXBias 14144 RX pwr: 0 TX pwr: 7184\n", "(?<=Vcc: ).*?(?=TXBias)").ToString`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov thank you yes that works. Would you please add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes your answer is most succinct but I can't get rid of the whitespace character before the "3220" which I would like to. I thought I could just use `(?<=Vcc: )(\s+\w+){2}` (if you can see the space after "Vcc:") but that was not a valid expression.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I do prefer what you're doing there because it allows me to take the next two strings without knowing anything that proceeds those.

Comment: Try this to get rid of the white space before 3220: (?<=Vcc:\s)(\s*\w+){2}.  Just slight modification to Wash's answer.

Comment: @dustmouse woot! Worked. Would you please write an answer explaining what is going on with the `\s`, and `\s*\w+` ? Thank you.

Comment: I'll give Wash the opportunity to provide an answer.  But basically, (?<=Vcc:\s) says that the match should immediately follow "Vcc: ", using something called a positive lookbehind, and \s*\w+ says the match can be spaces followed by characters or just characters.  So "3220 mV" fits that criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dustmouse's comment.

Well, you can do a *positive lookbehind* in this way:

`(?<=Vcc:\s)`

The previous line means that the regex will search for `Vcc:`, and, without matching will put the *cursor* after that.

Now, you can use a group `(...)`, but without saving, so it will be like this `(?:...)`.

Inside this group you can use `\s*` that means as many spaces as possible, followed by `\S+` that means *at least* one non-space.

Now, the group is formed:

`(?:\s*\S+)`

Why did you used a group? Just because now you can say how many times you want it to repeat like `{2}` (2x times), or `{5}` (5x times), and so on..

After all, the *tour* ends up with this Regular Expression:

`(?<=Vcc:\s)(?:\s*\S+){2}`

[Tested on regex101 site.](https://regex101.com/r/jJ0tJ3/3)

---

Bonus: I will say that as bonus, because depending on the language it won't work.

You can use `\K` to clear the matched `Vcc:`. If it is available in your language, you should prefer that because it increases the performance:

Instead of `(?<=Vcc\s)` you can use `Vcc\s+\K`.

1. Positives lookbehind don't allow `+` or `*` inside them. Look that now the text `Vcc:` will be matched with all spaces instead of only one space.
2. `\K` does the trick here. It clears the previous selection and starts from that point.

The final Regular Expression in this case would be:

`Vcc:\s+\K(?:\s*\S+){2}`

[Also tested on regex101 site.](http://Vcc:%5Cs+%5CK(?:%5Cs*%5CS%20)%7B2%7D)

---

One against another.

If you look at regex101:

The first alternative does 30 steps.

While the second does 14 steps !

Yeah! It is half a time !!

---

Let me know if anything was confuse.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest another, more efficient approach: using [`Groups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Look-arounds are known to be resource-consuming, and are only necessary when we need overlapping matches.

In this case, we have a fixed context, `Vcc:`, then space(s), some digits, space(s), `mV`, space(s), `TXBias`. We can *capture* (and that is what you did) what we want with parentheses. However, your regex has `.*?` lazy dot matching that actually just captured anything between spaces. I suggest just capturing the digits, or - if there can be any sequence of non-whitespace symbols - those symbols that are not whitespace.

```
Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("Vcc:\s+(\d+)\s+mV\s+TXBias") ' This regex captures digits
' Or, you can use this regex capturing non-whitespace sequence
' Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("Vcc:\s+(\S+)\s+mV\s+TXBias")
' Or, if you prefer your own regex to match "3220 mV", use it:
' Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("Vcc:\s+(.*?)\s+TXBias")
Dim match As Match = MyRegex.Match("CH1: Vcc: 3220 mV TXBias 14144 RX pwr: 0 TX pwr: 7184")
If match.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1).Value)
End If
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Y4C6dh), the output is `3220`, or here is [the one that outputs `3220 mV`](http://ideone.com/YDWoRv). You can move parentheses to capture any part of the adjoining text to it.

The `\s+` stands for 1 or more whitespace characters.

The `match.Groups(1).Value` holds the text captured by the first (and only) parenthetical group in our pattern. The 0th group is the whole match.

If we compare performance with http://regexhero.net, `Vcc:\s+(.*?)\s+TXBias` yields 429,380 iterations per second, and `(?<=Vcc: ).*?(?=TXBias)` yields 92,772:

[image]

So, use look-arounds only when necessary.